# No odd-length cycles imply no odd-length closed walks - proof by contradiction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I wanted to ask for feedback on a proof I did. It took me some time and reading a few different resources to grok what's going on in that proof, so I wanted to formulate my understanding in a proof in my own words.

---

**Claim**: If a graph $G$ does not contain any cycles with odd length, then $G$ does not contain any closed walks with odd length.

**Proof**, by contradiction: Assume for purpose of contradiction that $G$ does not contain any cycles with odd length, but indeed does contain a closed walk with odd length.

We assume $w = v_0, v_1, ..., v_k$ of length $k$ to be the shortest closed walk of odd length in $G$.

Since there are no odd length cycles in $G$, $w$ can't be a cycle either and has to be a closed proper walk. By the definition of proper walks, $v_i = v_j$ for some $0 \le i < j < k$ in $w$:

$$w = v_0, ..., v_i, ..., v_j, ..., v_k$$

Let the number of edges from $v_i$ to $v_j$ be $n$.

Now we can split $w$ into two closed walks

$$w' = v_i, ..., v_j$$ of length $n$ and 
$$w'' = v_0, ..., v_i, v_{j+1}, ..., v_k$$ of length $k - n$.

Since the length $k$ of $w$ was odd, either $n$ is odd or $k-n$ is odd. This shows that we can find a shorter closed walk with odd length in $G$ than $w$, contradicting our assumption that $w$ was the shortest closed walk.

Comment: There are some typos (you surely don't mean $0 \leq i < j \leq 0$, and I don't think you mean $w_k$ either). And the word "bipartite" is useless here; all that you want to say is in the condition "no cycles of odd length". Finally, there is no "cycle/walk"-dichotomy: cycles are walks too!

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thanks you are right, I fixed the typos and removed bipartite from the proof text. What do you mean with _ there is no "cycle/walk"-dichotomy: cycles are walks too!_ - I mean, I agree cycles are walks, too. But are you referring to some specific sentence?

Comment: " - If $w'$ is of odd length, then it must be a walk, or, if $w''$ is of odd length, then it must be a walk - we know this because $G$ does not contain any cycles of odd length.". This one. You aren't using the "no cycles of odd length" condiiton here.

Comment: But I do, no? By saying "…because $G$ does not contain any cycles of odd length." Or should I leave that sentence out completely, because it's too explicit? Btw. your comments already helped me, so feel free to write them as an answer as feedback, I will accept it.

Comment: You've already used the "no cycles of odd length" condition earlier on when you found $i$ and $j$. No need for it any more. Both $w'$ and $w''$ are closed walks because they end where they start.

Comment: I see what you mean, I think I mainly added that sentence as an explanation for myself, so to say. It is kind of clunky and redundant. Thanks a lot for your feedback!

Comment: Please update your title to a more describing. This has not much to do with bipartite graphs - at least it's not obvious what it has to do with bipartite graphs.

Comment: @skyking yeah that's true, it's not so obvious. The claim is part of a proof that shows some other properties of bipartite graphs, but this one was the hardest one for me to grok, so I only wrote a proof myself for that. It's of course not clear for others was the actual context was from which I took that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basically good, but since a cycle is a special case of closed walk  and that a walk don't have to be closed you should probably have written:

> Since there are no odd length cycles in $G$, $w$ can't be a cycle either and has to be a **closed proper** walk. By the definition of **proper** walks, $v_i=v_j$ for some $0\le i<j<k$ in $w$

That is both tell that the walk is both closed and proper (that is non-cycle).

Also probably a typo: $w''$ should be $v_0,\dots,v_i,v_{j+1},\dots,v_k$ (otherwise both are not shorter than $v$).

Comment: Thanks, good addition with the _proper_, that makes it much clearer.